# Symlink race condition vulnerability Support for cPanel

Tags: patch

How can I fix this issue in WHM/Cpanel with Ubuntu 20.04? The documentation says to use the BlueHost fix but that it's not optimal for fixing the issue. Cloudlinux has several methods to fix it. There's no way--at present--to patch it with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: You're using Ubuntu Core 20?   Don't forget the *year* format products of Ubuntu have differences to the more widely used *year.month* products, ie. 20 & 20.40 are different systems, though 20 is a *flavor* of 20.04 Server.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm using Ubuntu v20.04.4 Standard

Comment: This is the WHM/cPanel documentation about patching it: 
 https://docs.cpanel.net/ea4/apache/symlink-race-condition-protection/

Comment: But WHM Security Advisor says this:  Apache Symlink Protection: the Bluehost provided Apache patch is in effect
It appears that the Bluehost provided Apache patch is being used to provide symlink protection. This is less than optimal.

Comment: Please edit & correct your question then, as providing specific & accurate details help us to help you. Also apply all security fixes & patches ASAP as 20.04.4 means you're some months behind on applying fixes. You can refer to https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ for the date of the ISO release of 20.04.5; but do note installed systems upgraded in the week(s) before the actual 20.04.5 ISO release date.   I'd suggest applying fixes, then trying again.   This isn't a forum, but Q&A site, and all additional detail should be in your question; comments are for readers.